# decrease magento first bite wait time

Tags: magento

I am working on a magento [website](http://industrialsafety.us/index.php)

if i check site loading speed takes around 9s .. 
Please help me to decrease its loading time .. I don't know what is taking in First bite waiting .

I have tried to fix with profiler but here issue is that i have enabled profiler via admin but cant able to see on this page . also i tried by config file , But there is no luck

Comment: This question is way too broad and doesn't give enough details.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

To see the profiler in frontent, you have to enable it from the admin panel (`System->Configuration->Developer->Debug->Profiler`) and then you have to uncomment the `Varien_Profiler::enable();` line in index.php .

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem when I developed the site for my company.
First thing to remember Magento is hogs the resourses therefore shared hosting IS NOT the solution. 
You have to be on VPS or Dedicated hosting..

1. Go to tools.pingdom.com/fpt/ and enter your site (Remember to click the closest location before testing).. I did a test from NY and it was 9 secs.

   2. I also noticed the index.php on your URL. Get rid of it and the load time goes down to 2.5 seconds. To completely remove this go to  Admin--> System--> Configuration--> Catalog--> Search Engine Optimization-->  change to following

Autogenerated Site Map Enable

Popular Search Terms Enable

Product URL Suffix .html

Category URL Suffix .html

Use Categories Path for Product URLs Yes

Create Permanent Redirect for URLs if URL Key Changed Yes

Page Title Separator -

Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories Yes

Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products Yes

Give this a go. There are also some other alternative that can be done for this.. But this is would normally fix it...